# Insuppressible Error when saving PowerPoint file in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

**Before this gets marked as a duplicate:** It is not, as all the other saving errors seem to get a different `MsgBox`.

I am writing a macro that opens and closes a PowerPoint Presentation from Excel. Now I have the issue that when I am trying to save the PowerPoint file I get a pop up Message Box:

[image: ErrorMessage]

It says: "PowerPoint-Error while saving the file."
My code:

```
Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application

Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application

strPath = "S:\Folderxy\"
strFile = "filename.pptm"
strSave = "newFilename"

Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Open(strPath & strFile, False, True, True)

Application.DisplayAlerts = False


On Error GoTo Errorhandler_tryAgain

tryAgain:
    pptApp.DisplayAlerts = ppAlertsNone
    strSave = "Test123"
    pptPres.SaveAs strPath & strSave & ".pptx"
    pptPres.Close

Exit Sub

Errorhandler_tryAgain:
      Debug.Print "Errorhandler_tryAgain was opened!"
      Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now) 'delay in seconds
      GoTo TryAgain
```

> **First:**
>
> Even though I turned the `DisplayAlerts` off this one keeps popping up. However I can not easily reproduce this error. It occurs sometimes. Openening, closing and saving `*.pptx` files is part of a loop and surprisingly this error does not reoccur at the same file but it reoccurs about 2 times in a loop with 70 >files.
>
> **Second:**
>   When I manually click enter the `RuntimeError 70: Permission Denied` is thrown. But then the VBE goes into the debug mode and my Errorhandler is not handling it. The Errohandler is an infinitive loop as I am saving the file on a server and sometimes it fails to save. However when I manually tried to save the document (both, on the server and on the desktop) I got the same "PowerPoint-Error while saving the file." `MsgBox`.

Now my question is how do I either get rid of the saving error (which seems to be impossible) or how to surppress that error so that my macro does not stop everytime it occurs. As I would like to run the macro overnight.

In case anyone has experienced such a thing before and can help me out I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `strPath`? The reason I ask is because in one you are not using "\" `strPath & strFile` and in the other you are using it. `strPath & "\" & strSave & ".pptx"`

Comment: You have `GoTo SaveAgain` but the only label in the code (apart from the error handling block) is called `tryAgain`. Is this a typo or is there more code that isn't shown here?

Comment: I added what `strPath`, `strFile` and `strSave` look like. Also `GoTo SaveAgain` is indeed `GoTo TryAgain`. I edited my question.
Yes there is more code, a lot more than shown here. I fill diagrams, tables and textframes with data from my Excel workbook. As well as adding some pictures. But the code may not work at a point in the loop but if i rerun it the error does not appear at the same point in the loop.

Comment: `strPath = "S\Folderxy"` This is not a valid path

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.

Comment: Try this `pptPres.SaveAs strPath & strSave & ".pptx",1` and then add one line `DoEvents` and finally add this `pptPres.Close(False)`

Comment: I will try it thanks :) It takes a long while for my macro to run. So I will probably only be able to tell you by tomorrow if it worked or not ;)

Comment: Whenever you are commenting, add "@" and then the name so that I can get an alert :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout The error did not occur again tonight. However all files are now saved in the `.ppt` file format. Checking with the docs I will try to save it as `.pptx` and then I will run it again tonight. 
Also `pptPres.Close(False)` returned "Wrong amount of arguments". So I went back to `pptPres.Close`

Comment: For parameters see [Presentation.SaveAs method (PowerPoint)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.saveas)

Comment: @SiddharthRout you sure? I used `ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation` which is 24?
Yea thanks for the link :)
Also I deleted the `& ".pptx"` as it would save it as `".pptx.pptx"` ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I will see if it will still work or if the error will reoccur. I will keep you updated.

Comment: `Also I deleted the & ".pptx" as it would save it as ".pptx.pptx"` I went with `strSave = "newFilename"` which did not have "pptx" ;)

Comment: @SiddharthRout I tested it again and it fixed the problem. If you want you can write it to an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Glad it was fixed. posted it.

Comment: I have the same issue Permission denied error and Error Handling does not catch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these two things and you should be ok...

1. Mention the File Format while saving. For example `pptPres.SaveAs strPath & strSave & ".pptx",24 '<~~ ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation`. Also ensure the `strPath & strSave & ".pptx"` is the extact name of the fiel as you wanted it. Else tweak the variables accordingly.
2. Always add `DoEvents` after you issue the save(or save as) statement and before the `.Close` statement so Excel can get enough time to finish it's tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Application.Wait suspends all Excel activity including execution of your macro. It's not so useful for fixing timing problems. When I want to add a little time so that the program can finish I/O or clipboard tasks, Sleep is a better option. First add a declaration:

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
```

Add error-trapping before the problem statement, including a statement to reset error handling after the problem:

```
TryCut1:
  On Error GoTo TooFast1
  objShape.TextFrame2.TextRange.Cut
  On Error GoTo -1
```

Then add this for error handling. It waits for 10 milliseconds, then tries again:

```
TooFast1:
  Sleep 10
  Resume TryCut1
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, the Errorhandler **does not** pick up the error. Therefore I can not use an Errorhandler to solve my problem.

Comment: Your code has 2 problems: the use of Wait, which halts Excel, and the lack of error handling resetting, which means the error handler can only run once.